# Is FNP = FEXPTIME if and only if NP = EXPTIME?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

It is very well known that if the classes $\sf FP$ and $\sf FNP$ are equal, then also the classes $\sf P$ and $\sf NP$ are equal (see e.g. [FNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNP_%28complexity%29) on Wikipedia).

Is it also true that if $\sf FNP=FEXPTIME$ then also $\sf NP=EXPTIME$?  (See the [exponential time conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis).)  I did find [a paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.7053.pdf) constructing real functions that are in $\sf FEXPTIME$.

Comment: If it was trivial and direct, would you not already have a proof?

Comment: ... er, FNP is a class of relations and FEXPTIME is a class of functions. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, aren't FP, FNP, FEXP and Fblah (for any blah) all defined formally as classes of binary relations? Moreover, a function is a binary relation anyway.

Comment: If they're defined like that then $\:$FP = FNP$\;$. $\;\;\;$ (How else could FP be defined?) $\hspace{1.67 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer, FP is the class of binary relations Pxy for which y can be computed in deterministic polynomial time given x, or equivalently the subclass of FNP that can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: By that definition, every relation in FP is the graph of a function. $\:$ On the other hand, $\{\langle \text{"0","0"}\rangle,\langle \text{"0","1"}\rangle \}$ is in FNP but is not the graph of a function. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, sorry, that should say "for which _some_ y ... such that Pxy holds" (so it doesn't have to be a function). Also, this discussion is getting too long for the comments, we should cut it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, vacuously, since it is trivial that $\operatorname{FNP} \neq \operatorname{FEXPTIME}$, because it takes an exponentially long amount of time to give an exponentially long output.

Comment: Presumably FEXPTIME is defined so that $|y|$ is polynomial in $|x|$.